# Use pdist() in python with a custom distance function defined by you

Tags: python, scipy, distance

I have been interested in usage of [`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(...)`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) in python which has come to be useful and fast for some of the applications I have been working on.

I need to use a pairwise distance function which are custom and not standard default distance metrics as defined by the metric. Let's make a simple example, suppose I do not want to use `euclidean` distance function as the following:

```
 Y = pdist(X, 'euclidean')
```

Instead I want to define the euclidean function myself and pass it as a function or argument to `pdist()`. How can I pass the implementation of `euclidean` distance function to this function to get exactly the same results. The answer to this question, will help me to use the function in the way I am interested in.

In MATLAB, I know how to use `pdist()`, in Python I don't yet. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is an example in the [documentation for `pdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.17.0/reference/generated/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

dm = pdist(X, lambda u, v: np.sqrt(((u-v)**2).sum()))
```

If you want to use a regular function instead of a lambda function the equivalent would be

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

def dfun(u, v):
    return np.sqrt(((u-v)**2).sum())

dm = pdist(X, dfun)
```

Comment: how to use the new distance metric in seaborn's hierarchical clustering function ```sns.clustermap(X, metric=dm)```? Trying just this produced an error when $X$ is a square matrix